# How can I find an angle of rotated geometry?

Tags: python-3.x, rotation, 2d, pca, computational-geometry

I have 2d geometry and corresponding X and Y coordinates. How can find the rotation angle (in degree) of geometry with respect to X or Y axis? Suggestions will always be welcomed.

```
X = [0.71, 1.41, 2.12, 2.83, 2.12, 2.83, 3.54, 4.24, 4.95, 5.66, 4.95, 4.24, 3.54, 2.83, 2.12, 1.41]

Y = [-0.71, 0.0, 0.71, 1.41, 2.12, 2.83, 2.12, 1.41, 0.71, 0.0, -0.71, 0.0, 0.71, 0.0, -0.71, -1.41]
```

I have mentioned coordinates as above. **My aim is to align the geometry's principal axis to the X or Y coordinates.**

Comment: What do you mean by the geometry's principal axis? I drew this shape and it's sort of a "T" shape. Do you know that it will always be a T-shape?

Comment: Yes, I want to write a code in such a way which can find the principal axis of the geometry having X, Y or X, Y, Z coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find a principal axis, I have applied Principal Componenet Analysis (PCA).

I created a dataframe of X and Y coordinate. Then,

First I centered the geometry considering the mean of X and Y coordinate.

```
data_centered1 = df_1.apply(lambda x: x-x.mean())     
data_centered1
```

Then I separated a list of X and Y coordinate (after centering) to two different list.

Then to apply PCA, I followed these steps,

(1) compute covariance matrix

```
def create_covariance_matrix(data_matrix):
    n = data_matrix.shape[0]
    cov_matrix = (1 / (n - 1)) * np.dot(data_matrix.T, data_matrix)
    return cov_matrix

cov_matrix = create_covariance_matrix(first_coord)
```

(2) Compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors from covariance matrix

```
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(cov_matrix)
```

(3) find the angle of first principal component

```
alpha = np.degrees(np.arctan(eigenvectors[1][1]/eigenvectors[0][1]))
beta = 90-alpha
```

(4) visulize a plot with original geometry with principal component

```
plt.scatter(X1_coordinate, Y1_coordinate)
plt.plot([0, eigenvectors[0][1]], [0, eigenvectors[1][1]], marker = 'o')
plt.show()
```

(5) Rotate all points of geometry with the angle obtained from eigenvectors (either alpha or beta). It will rotate the geometry such that geometry's principal axis aligned with global reference system axis.

I followed these steps and it works fine!!